# About image size, and resolutions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When we create UI components for our iPhone applications, why do we create images in 2 resolutions. (I understand that this is because of high and low resolution iphones and ipod touch). But when we try to add an image programatically what image out of the 2 should we add (Is it the image with high resolution or the image with Low resolution)

2.) How will the device (iphone/ipod) know which image to load (to load the high or low resolution one)

note:  i have already gone through this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "But when we try to add an image programatically..."?

Comment: Adding an image to a button using code (without using IB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name your low-resolution image: `MyImage.png`

The corresponding high-resolution image must then be named: `MyImage@2x.png`

The device knows its own resolution and will pick the right one automatically. In your code simply always refer to the low-resolution name.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]
```